# Question from Wilf's generatingfunctionology on ordered representations of $n$ as a sum of $k$ distinct integers.

Tags: generating-functions

This is a question from Wilf's *generatingfunctionology*, Chapter 2, Exercise 21(a) and (b) (p. 71 in the 3rd edition).

> (a) Let $T$ be a fixed set of nonnegative integers.  Let $f(n,k,T)$ be the number of ordered representations of $n$ as a sum of $k$ integers chosen from $T$.  Find $\sum_n f(n,k,T)x^n$.
>
> (b)Let $g(n,k,T)$ be the number of ordered representations of $n$ as a sum of $k$ *distinct* integers chosen from $T$.  Find $\sum_n g(n,k,T)x^n$.

For part (a) I wrote, for $t_i \in T$

$$\begin{align*} 
f(n,k,T) &= \sum_{t_1 + \cdots + t_k = n} 1 \\
&= \sum_{t_1 + \cdots + t_k =n} a_{t_1} \cdot \cdots \cdot a_{t_k} & \text{where } a_{t_i} = 1 \ \forall \, i\\
\end{align*}
$$

Then, by the power rule for ordinary power series generating functions, we have

$$
\left\{ f(n,k,T) \right\}_{n=0}^{\infty} \leftrightarrow \left( \{ 1\}_{t \in T} \right)^k = \left(\sum_{t \in T} x^t \right)^k.
$$

This agrees with the answer provided in the book, but I'm a little uncertain that my final steps are justified (I'm mostly concerned about taking the sum over $t \in T$).

For part (b) the book provides the solution

$$
\sum_n g(n,k,T) x^n = [y^k] \prod_{t \in T}(1+yx^t)
$$

I'm at a loss how to arrive at this.

**Edited:**
Part (c) of this question was asked here: [Find the Generating Function with respect to n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772051/find-the-generating-function-with-respect-to-n), though the answer doesn't seem to shed light on parts (a) and (b) above.

Comment: Have you read Robert Sedgewick and Phillipe Flajolet "Analytic Combinatorics".?  I think Part A on the symbolic method might help answer your question.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Thanks, I'll try to look at that and see if I can understand it.

Comment: If you look at the coefficient of $[y^k]$ on the RHS, you have $\sum\limits_{t_1 < \ldots < t_k \in T} x^{t_1 + \ldots + t_k}$, which is indeed the opsgf of $g(n,k,T)$.  The intuition for having a $y$ in there is that it only allows you to use each $t$ once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Case (b):**
>
> Since we are looking for ordered representations of $n$ as a sum of $k$ *distinct* integers chosen from $T$, each element $t\in T$ can occur at most once.
>
> To select an element $t\in T$ exactly zero or one times is encoded with
>   $$x^{0\cdot t}+x^{1\cdot  t}=1+x^t$$

We observe: The product

$$\prod_{t\in T}(1+x^t)=\sum_{n\geq 0}g(n,T)x^n$$

encodes $g(n,T)$ the number of possibilities $n$ can be represented as sum of elements of $T$, whereby each element occurs zero or one times. Note, the RHS is the expansion according to $x$ and  therefore we sum up with respect to the powers of $x$ (i.e. $n\geq 0$).

The number of ordered representations of $n$ as sum of *distinct* integers is therefore

$$[x^n]\prod_{t\in T}(1+x^t)=[x^n]\sum_{m\geq 0}g(m,T)x^m=g(n,T)\qquad\qquad n\geq 0$$

> But this product does not provide any information about the number $k$ of summands which are used. We encode this particular information by *counting the number* of summands. This is done by  multiplying each occurrence of $x^t$ by $y$.
>
> \begin{align*}
> \prod_{t\in T}(1+yx^t)=\sum_{j\geq 0}\sum_{n\geq 0}g(n,k,T)x^ny^j\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> Observe, that $y^j$ implies that $j$ elements from $T$ are selected to form a sum. Now we are interested in finding the number of representations with $k$ *distinct* integers and we therefore select from (1) the series in $x$ corresponding to $y^k$.
>
> \begin{align*}
> [y^k]\prod_{t\in T}(1+yx^t)=[y^k]\sum_{j\geq 0}\sum_{n\geq 0}g(n,k,T)x^ny^j=\sum_{n\geq 0}g(n,k,T)x^n\qquad\qquad k\geq 0
> \end{align*}

A remark to the first part.

> **Case (a):**
>   The series
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{t\in T}x^t
> \end{align*}
>   represents the selection of exactly one element $t$ from $T$. The $k$-th power means to select $k$ elements from $T$ and summing them up. So, when expanding the series with respect to $x$ we get the representation.
>   \begin{align*}
> (\sum_{t\in T}x^t)^k=\sum_{n\geq 0}f(n,k,T)x^n
> \end{align*}